# Using Selenium with Python not working in google chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

i have code it opens website in chrome for this code but it does not go further

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login')
driver.find_element("username").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element("password").send_keys("admin123")
driver.close()
```

---

Result this one

i need answer how to solve this problem

Comment: What exactly not works? Getting any errors?

Comment: That's typical behavior when your drivers are out of sync with the browser.

Answer (score -1):

The way you are initializing your webdriver and selecting the input elements seem to be the problem.

Try doing it this way instead.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']").send_keys("admin123")
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

You may also check out selenium's quick start guide [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: Thanks can you also share of Button code that is Login https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login'    in this website    i try this code but its not working   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Login']").click()

Comment: I recommend visiting the link included in the post or reading up on finding elements by XPATH.